# @ngrx/router-store/index has no exported member 'RouterReducerState'

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

I am trying to work on @ngrx/router-store. i am getting this error `@ngrx/router-store/index has no exported member 'RouterReducerState'`. I am using version **1.2.6** of `@ngrx/router-store`

Comment: which @ngrx/router-store version you're using

Comment: i am using version 1.2.6

Comment: try to update to a newer version 6.1.0: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngrx/router-store

Comment: that worked. Thank you

Comment: you're welcome, I'm gonna put it as answer for others. Good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to a newer the latest version : `@ngrx/router-store 6.1.0`

see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngrx/router-store